# Not able to connect to remote database after migration

Tags: 8, database

I am moving a running site from staging to production. The production environment has 2 servers, one for frontend and the other for the database.

The issue is when I try to browse the website, I get this error

> PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied in [ROOT]/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php on line 79

The real problem is I am sure that the database connection is set right. Permissions and ports are set right.

I tried the same database connection info from an external PHP file on the same server and I got successfully connected.

Also, I tried `drush st` and it told me that database status is Connected, and Drupal bootstrap status is Success.

Even tried `drush sqlc` and I got connected to the remote database. I can list tables, execute queries, etc.

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: The mentioned php file - did you executed it from CLI or browser? Is it possible that you're using two different php configs - one for CLI and another for apache/fpm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're using SELinux see [this article](https://alexbilbie.com/2013/02/selinux-php-mysql/).

> setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
>
> setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess- 
I saw that error after making some changes to my MAMP environment (specifically, I upgraded MAMP Pro). It turned out that the server was using one version of PHP, and the CLI (e.g., DRUSH) was using another. When I got one to work, the other would fail.

When I got both environments using the same PHP version, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score -2):

In the `sites/default/settings.php` file, change the value of `host` key from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.

**Code sample**

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'foo',
  ...
  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
);
```

Comment: But he said that db host is a remote host...